# How to remove 2 or more special characters of a particular column value using spark sql function : regexp_replace?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a column "GEOGRAPHY" having value as AS^ASI^BA

I need to filter out the characters ^A and ^B so that I get the output as ASIA

I tried the below function but replacing the unwanted characters by '', but it is not working

```
regexp_replace(GEOGRAPHY, '^A', '' ) as GEOGRAPHY"
regexp_replace(GEOGRAPHY, '^B', '' ) as GEOGRAPHY"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `regex or` using `|` to match  **`("\\^A|\\^B")`**.

```
//sample data
df.show()
//+---------+
//|GEOGRAPHY|
//+---------+
//|A^ASI^BA|
//+---------+
df.withColumn("new_col",regexp_replace(col("GEOGRAPHY"),("\\^A|\\^B"),"")).show()
//+---------+-------+
//|GEOGRAPHY|new_col|
//+---------+-------+
//|A^ASI^BA|  ASIA  |
//+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `|` to join `^A` and `^B`

```sql
regexp_replace(GEOGRAPHY, '^A|^B', '') as GEOGRAPHY
```

ps: if your `^A` is not one character, you need add `\\` such as `\\^A`